# Get channel of Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, version, firefox-addon-webextensions

Anyone have a function that works in the extensions that determines Firefox channel (ESR/Stable/Beta/Dev/Nightly) without any fetch requests and without estimates?

We can of course estimate based on what we know about the release cycle but it's not accurate:

```
function getChannelFromVersion(version) {
    const nightlySeedDate = new Date(2018, 10, 27);
    const nightlySeedVersion = 66;

    const cycleWeeks = 9;
    const cycleTime = cycleWeeks * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // ms

    const weeksBetweenSeed = (Date.now() - nightlySeedDate.getTime()) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 7;
    let versionBetweenSeed = weeksBetweenSeed / cycleWeeks;
    versionBetweenSeed = versionBetweenSeed < 0 ? Math.floor(versionBetweenSeed) : Math.ceil(versionBetweenSeed);

    const currentNightlyVersion = nightlySeedVersion + versionBetweenSeed;

    // console.log('weeksBetweenSeed:', weeksBetweenSeed, 'versionBetweenSeed:', versionBetweenSeed, 'currentNightlyVersion:', currentNightlyVersion);

    const diffVersion = currentNightlyVersion - version;
    if (diffVersion < 0) return 'unreleased';
    else if (diffVersion === 0 ) return 'nightly';
    else if (diffVersion === 1 ) return 'dev';
    else if (diffVersion === 2 ) return 'beta';
    else if (diffVersion === 3 ) return 'stable';
    else return 'outdated';

}

// getChannelFromVersion(59) === "nightly"
```

Comment: Why those tags specifically? "Works in the web" doesn't explain what extensions have to do with it.

Comment: @Xan thanks - I updated it to be "Works in extensions". I need to know if ESR/stable/beta or dev/nightly, because the instructions/tutorial to launch vary depending on the channel.

Comment: Ok, that's more clear now then.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to do this directly, but one has been proposed:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1386076

Comment: Dang. No other way, like feature detection or something?